# What does box-sizing:border-box; do in website?

Tags: css

I am actually seeking A really simple and short answer, my discord friends kept telling me that I should write it every time I start programming a website and so on I did without actually knowing what it really does and Impacts.

Comment: The MDN documentation explains it well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)
hope its help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`box-sizing:border-box;` defines how the elements are calculated i.e. height and width & do they really need padding and borders, these properties are taken care of `box-sizing:border-box;`. With `box-sizing: border-box;`, we can change the box model to an unusual way, where an element's specified width and height do not get affected by padding or borders. This has become so useful which helps in a responsive design that it's found its way into reset styles. You can find this [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Browser_compatibility) of browsers which supports `box-sizing:border-box;`

Comment: The question is asking for opinion which is off topic here on SO. *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.* Please don't answer off topic questions: [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)